# ffmpeg take snapshot from webcam in windows 10

Tags: ffmpeg

Attempting to use ffmpeg to grab a snapshot from my USB webcam in windows 10.

`ffmpeg -f mjpeg "video=HD Pro Webcam C920" "C:\projects\webcam\" -vframes 1 -s 1920x1080 -ss 10 test.jpg`

Returns: `Output #0, mjpeg, to 'video=HD Pro Webcam C920':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream`

I think I might have something backwards here, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using DirectShow (dshow) input and make a JPG snapshot:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i "video=HD Pro Webcam C920" -frames:v 1 test.jpg
```

Print the list of dshow supported devices and exit:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

Print the list of supported options in selected device and exit:

```
ffmpeg -list_options true -f dshow -i "video=HD Pro Webcam C920"
```

See [FFmpeg dshow documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow) for more info.